# PHP/MySQL - Hashing To BIGINT To Ensure No Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, hash, transactions

I'm currently scraping virtual currency transaction data off a webpage. The transactions consist of time/date, a description, price, and new balance.

Results are paginated. I can fetch 20 at a time. My goal is to have an accurate record of all entries in a separate database. There are a very large number of transactions occurring, and transactions can occur at any time, including between fetching different pages.

Time/date is measured to the minute, so multiple transactions can occur in the same minute. Descriptions can also be the same (for example the same item can be sold in the same quantity to the same person multiple times). Both price and balance could also overlap.

I am storing a timestamp, price, balance, and data which is parsed from the description in multiple fields. I need to be able to tell if an entry is already in the database quickly. The maximum effect I could get is to ensure that each entry has a unique time/data, description, price, and balance. The issue with composite keys is that I don't want to store the full description in the database. (This would double the database size.)

My solution that I came up with was to create a BIGINT hash based on those fields, which would be used as a UNIQUE field in the database. I found that the probability of a collision ([based on the birthday attack formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics)) would be less than 1% for up to 61 million entries, which is a satisfactory probability, since the number of entries I'm planning to track is in the neighbourhood of 40k-2m.

My question is, based on my application and goals, which hashing algorithm would you recommend and how can I get the values from it in to a BIGINT size without losing any of the properties of the algorithm? The most important thing is to avoid collisions, as each one would affect the integrity of the data. Unless you have a better idea, my plan was to concatenate the data into a string (with separators between fields) then feed it into the function. Short code snippets are much appreciated!

Comment: You wrote "comparing against all these fields during a MySQL INSERT query would be slow".  What's your evidence for that? Or are you guessing that it's true? If you make them into a composite unique key and do INSERT IGNORE, your problem should be solved quite neatly.

Comment: A composite index across the four columns would enable you to perform lookups quicker than hashing... and would deliver exactly what you want.  However, the transactions must themselves have a unique identifier of some sort—is scraping the webpage really the only way you can obtain them?  Many virtual currencies expose a blockchain that you could access directly...

Comment: I don't know enough about how composite keys work to analyze performance, however my intuition tells me that doing a comparison against one BIGINT would have to be faster than comparing against multiple string fields.

I would also prefer not to store the entire description in the database, as would be necessary for composite keys. This description is a sentence with a lot of useless words in between the key data, and would likely double the size of the database.

Comment: It's not just "a comparison against one BIGINT" though... you have to *calculate the hash* first!  This versus directly walking an index tree for a combined key that's only a few bytes larger than a `BIGINT`?  I'd almost certainly bet on the latter.

Comment: Right. I was thinking that hashing was a one-time thing for the insert and forgot that the hashing has to be done again for every comparison anyways. So now the only disadvantage is storing the description. Last time the data got so large I couldn't easily export it, though I suppose that will happen in either case. I don't need the description for any other reason.

Comment: There is one additional complexity. The time accuracy is to seconds initially, however only to minutes after a certain period of time. I want to capture the seconds accuracy if I can, however older transactions would compute to a different timestamp based on minutes and fail to register as duplicates. So I have to store both an accurate (seconds) and less accurate (minutes) field.

There's one additional consideration. Because transactions are sequential, I only need to test the first and last entry in a page to know if that page has been done, making this 25 times faster (50 entries/page).

Comment: I still think it should be possible to compute a simple hash in n time, as fast as the comparison. A simple summation would do this, though it wouldn't have random distribution properties.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't care about security, I used SHA1. This generates a 20-byte hexadecimal string. BIGINT is 8 bytes in size. Therefore, we need to truncate to 16 characters (since each character is half a byte in hex) using substr, and use base_convert to convert to base 10 for database storage.

```
function hashToBigInt ($string) {
  return base_convert(substr(sha1($string), 0, 16), 16, 10);
}
```

Thanks everyone for all your help!